# How to execute similar action from Package Manager Console like programmatic Database.EnsureCreated()?

Tags: entity-framework-core, command-line-interface, package-manager-console

I can execute EF Core's `Database.EnsureCreated()` programmatically, when my web application starts, and everything EF Core related code in place, and is working properly.

Is there any way to execute something similar from PM> console? (just like `add-migration` or `update-database`), but I do not want any migration, just the same effect what executing `Database.EnsureCreated()` from code.

Comment: Maybe add-migration, update-database, then simply delete migration folder?

Comment: many thx, it is a workaround